# Error while running EAS build for React Native Expo Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, eas

I tried building my app previously using EAS build there was no error but I guess when I changed my icon and splash images I am getting this error. Even though I checked everything like path to the icon and splash screen image, formatting conventions, resolutions etc.the error is still there. Below is the error that I received in Run gradlew.

I am not sure whether the error occurred due to replacement of the icon and splash screen as the path and formats are as per the requirement. Below is my app.json file

```
**[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 
1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr]
```

## -----------**

```
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
 [stderr] 
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
[stderr] 
> A failure occurred while executing     com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
[stderr]
```

> Android resource compilation failed
> [stderr]
> ERROR:/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable- mdpi/src_assets_logo.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
> [stderr]

```
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
==============================================================================
[stderr] 
2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
-----------
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
==============================================================================
[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 5m 40s


{
  "expo": {
    "name": "medicine",
    "slug": "medicine",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "ghritak.medicine"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "ghritak.medicine"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "ccc84013-b406-45b4-a99a-3d4cf6197ae8"
      }
    }
  }
}
```